# Plotly Dash app doesen't seem to update the app.layout property when generating components on the fly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Dash seems to not update the app.layout attribute when creating components dynamically from callbacks. Below is a simple example that reproduces the unwanted behaviour:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    html.Button(id="display_graph",children="Show graph"),
    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),
    html.Div(id="graph_div", children=[]),
    html.Div(id="detiles", children=[])
])


@app.callback(
    Output('detiles', 'children'),
    [Input('graph', 'hoverData')])
def debug_hover(hover_data):
    children = []
    print(hover_data)
    if hover_data["points"] is not None:
        points = hover_data["points"]
        for p in points:
            print(p["curveNumber"])
            trace_name = app.layout['graph'].figure['data'][p["curveNumber"]]['name']
            # trace_name = "placeholder"
            children.append(html.Div(
                [html.P(f"Estimated Turnover:{trace_name}: {p['value']}", style={"display": "inline-block"})]))
        return children



@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph_div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='display_graph', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_country):
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    y1 = [i*2 for i in x]
    y2 = [i * 3 for i in x]
    y3 = [i * 4 for i in x]
    fig = {
        'data': [
            {'x': x, 'y': y1, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Basic model',
             "marker_color": 'rgb(55, 83, 109)'},
            {'x': x, 'y': y2, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'New model',
             "marker_color": 'rgb(185, 83, 109)'},
            {'x': x, 'y': y3, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Model V2',
             "marker_color": 'rgb(32, 201, 52)'}
        ],
        'layout': {
            'title': f"{input_country}",
            'xaxis': {'rangeslider': {"visible": True},
                      'range': [0, 20]},
            'height': 700,
            'width': 1200,
            'margin': {'b': 400}
        }
    }
    graph = dcc.Graph(id="graph", figure=fig)

    return graph


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The error I get in dash debugger looks like this:
[image]
Which implies that there is no "graph" element in `app.layout`, but clearly there should be a "graph" under children in "graph_div" component. The graph is created from a callback and clearly visible.

Even if I check the debugger in PyCharm and inspect the app.layout I see there is no expected dcc.Graph component in "graph_div" children
[image]

Is thi expected behaviour or is it a bug that needs to get looked into? If it is expected, is there any workaround to access properties of dynamically generated components, like trace names from existing graphs for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that I should pass a `State` to the callback. Modifying `debug_hover` like seen below solves my issue:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('detiles', 'children'),
    [Input('graph', 'hoverData')],
    [State("graph","figure")] # This was modified
)
def debug_hover(hover_data,figure): # This was modified
    children = []
    print(hover_data)
    if hover_data["points"] is not None:
        points = hover_data["points"]
        for p in points:
            print(p["curveNumber"])
            trace_name = figure['data'][p["curveNumber"]]['name'] # This was modified
            # trace_name = "placeholder"
            children.append(html.Div(
                [html.P(f"Estimated Turnover:{trace_name}: {p['value']}", style={"display": "inline-block"})]))
        return children
```